# Is it possible to create a specialized image on Azure with Terraform? How?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to create a specialized VM image on Azure with Terraform? How?  I have already uploaded the .vhd to a storage account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Currently, it's not possible to provision VM with Azure VM from a specialized image with built-in terraform. As a workaround, we can invoke the [PowerShell scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed) with `local-exec` Provisioner or deploy [ARM template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet/) with terraform.

From ArcturusZhang's comment in this [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine fails to create when referencing a "specialised" shared gallery image.](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7772),

> Despite that now azurerm provider supports creating specialized image,
> it does not support provision VMs or VMSSes by using the specialized
> images. It is implementing in [PR #7524](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/7524) but it is currently blocked by
> some inconsistency in the compute API of azure. Please stay tuned.

Also, when we [capture an image of the OS Disk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/image), currently, the only value is `Generalized` for `os_state` with `azurerm_image`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried this.  My problem is unless the VM is "specialized", Azure will try and configure login/password, etc., and the provisioning will return as failed.  It's a specialized image and I can't have them setting that anyway.

Comment: I am confused about your issue. Do you want to use Terraform to create a custom image from a specialized VM (.vhd) that you have uploaded to the Storage account? Or do you want to create a new Azure VM from that custom image with terraform?

Comment: In the end I want to create a VM from a specialized image.  But I'm having trouble even doing that.  (all with terraform).  I have the VHD ready, just it seems there is no support for specialized images.  I figured I would have to use Powershell.  Thoughts?  thank you for all your help.

Comment: I see. I miss the "specialized" image. I have updated my reply.